# Order items not showing in the shipping mail for the Store owner

Tags: orders, customer, shipping, magento2.4.3, mail

I upgraded the website from Magento 2.3.3 to version 2.4.3p2. When I do shipment of order then mail receives for both client and store owner.

But the issue is items are not displayed for the store owner's email. But working fine for the Client end.

I added the store owner's email along with others' emails but the only store owner not receiving items in the shipping mail which is really strange for me.

[image]

Can you please tell me why this happening in the case of the shipping email?

Comment: Any error on magento log file related to this one?

Comment: There is no error showing in log files.

Comment: @ManojJarial check your third-party extensions.